# How can we use latency compensation when the meteor method on server can fail?

Tags: meteor

Latency compensation is a nice trick to show immediate feedback to the user without having to wait for the server update to go through, and remove critical time delay.

But in many cases there could be a problem with the server method and the update/insert could fail. So latency compensation becomes a problem in these cases when there are chances that the server method might fail for any reason. In that case showing the user the immediate effects and then rolling back is very misleading.

So how can we use latency compensation without addressing this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution is to use a spinner-like indicator if the server roundtrip call takes more than X milliseconds, suggesting that the display is to be treated as "interim". If and when the [server method call](http://docs.meteor.com/#/basic/methods) does return, the indicator could turn into a ✔ checkmark.

> That's why Meteor has a feature called method stubs. If you define a method on the client with the same name as a server method, Meteor will run it to attempt to predict the outcome of the server method. When the code on the server actually finishes, the prediction generated on the client will be replaced with the actual outcome of the server method.

Failure (as in explicit error returned by the server) should be distinguished from a network error by throwing an [error message](https://atmospherejs.com/?q=flash+error), while the client being disconnected should display a [connection status](https://atmospherejs.com/?q=connection+status) message.

Comment: Yes I can imagine that in most cases it will work fine, but the server update might fail in some. So doesn't that create an inconsistent state? Then how can we safely use it when there is a chance that it might fail? 

I can see that showing the checkmark and spinner is a decent way to show update in progress, but still it gives the feeling that something is going which is not necessarily smooth enough for the user experience. And in case it fails then instead of the checkmark do we throw an error message?

Comment: Failure (as in explicit error returned by the server) should be distinguished from a network error. Failures, as you said, should result in an [error message](https://atmospherejs.com/?q=flash+error), while the client being disconnected should display a [connection status](https://atmospherejs.com/?q=connection+status) message. Updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks @Dan Dascalescu. Do you have any ideas to gracefully handle server error when using latency compensation? Lets take the same example where we can show a checkmark if it passes, else should we show a 'x' and show the error? I am not completely convinced about the user experience in this case.